# US short-term visa for an Indian citizen at the US-Canada border

Tags: usa, canada

I have a Indian passport and i I have a Canada visitor's visa. I will be in Canada for one month. After that is it possible for me to go to the US-Canada border and get a 1-week visa, so I can visit my sister for 3, 4 days?

If not, is there any other solution? I cannot apply for a US visa from India because I will be traveling to Canada on 18th July.

Answer (score 7):

You can apply for a US visa at a US consulate in Canada.  You cannot get one at the border.

But processing times in Canada can be [very long](https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/us-visas/visa-information-resources/wait-times.html).

For example, the wait time for an appointment in Toronto is 70 days.  Calgary and Quebec city are somewhat more reasonable at 14 days.

Comment: The embassy in Canada has also repeatedly warned that nonresidents of Canada, while they may apply, may have a more difficult time proving they qualify for the visa.

Comment: @MichaelHampton that is true.  But it could just be a standard disclaimer like "your visa does not guarantee entry into the United States."  It's hard to know *how* much more difficult a time a specific person would have, or what circumstances that question might depend on.

Answer (score -1):

You can ask at the consulate, but apart from the timescale, you'll have to prove to them that you're not using this visa as a backdoor to enter the USA illegally. Going to "visit your sister" is something they've probably heard many times before.

Probably easier/quicker for your sister to visit you in Canada.